# Big O Notation Summation confusion

Tags: big-o

I wish to use Big O Notation to convince others about code enhancement - both for efficiency and readability. But I am not sure whether i am wrong.

From Big O Notation, I understand that O(n) + O(n) = O(n) (approximate). Meaning, the constant in front is negligible.

However, taking an example, let say a for-loop

```
//Case 1: One For-Loop - O(n)
for(var i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   doA(i);
   doB(i);
}
```

For better readability, i prefer writing in this way:

```
//Case 2: Two For-Loop - O(n) + O(n)
function doA(){
   for(var i=0;i<n;i++){
     //do logic A
   }
}

function doB(){
   for(var i=0;i<n;i++){
      //do Logic B
   }
}
```

Such that, I can straightaway calling

```
doA();
doB();
```

...without the for-loop outside.

Now the problem is, i cannot convince myself, IF that for-loop actually takes 10 seconds. Then O(n) + O(n) is actually 20 seconds. How can we say that O(n) + O(n) is approximate-able to O(n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can we say that O(n) + O(n) is approximate-able to O(n)

For your (university) concerns, there *are four types* of complexity:

- logarithmical ( O(log(n)) )
- linear ( O(n) )
- polynomial ( O(n^k, k elemOf {1,2,3,...}) )
- exponential ( O(n^n) )

Your question refers to the second case:

In *Infinity* `O(n) + O(n)` is `O(n)`, because both are linear.
So you can think of it as

```
linear + linear = linear
```

Linear means that if you double the amount of input, the processing time doubles.

In the other, slower, cases the amount of processing time will be

- *n^2*, *n^3*, ... in the case of *polynomial complexity* (Doubling the amount of input results in *input^2*, *input^3* or *input^4* processing time)
- *n^n (which is really big/slow)* ... in the case of *exponential complexity* (Multiplying the amount of input by itself results in a processing time multiplied by itself, e.g. 3*3 = 9, 4*4 = 16, 5*5 = 25...).

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your explanation. Seems i cannot apply this to my case (use multiple for-loops for better readability)